# ngAnimate not adding classes with angular-material

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I'm building a single page application with angular material and for some reason the animations are not functioning.

It looks like it is not just angular material as I can't get the basic example on the https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations page to work.

It appears that the classes that angular material relies on to be added for the css animations to hook on to are not being applied. Inspecting the elements in chrome I just see the hide and show classes but none of the transition classes.

Relevant parts of my bower file:

`"angular": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-i18n": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "angular-material": "~0.9.8",`

My site (in development) is at http://www.zakhenry.com and the animation test page is at http://www.zakhenry.com/#/blog
When the viewport is small (ie mobile width) I *should* be able to see the sidepane animate out like on the https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ site; instead it just appears and disappears.

Source code is at https://github.com/xiphiaz/zakhenry.com

Comment: Did you declare a dependency to the `ngAnimate` module?

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck yep see http://www.zakhenry.com/js/config/vendorModules.js - and I can actually access the nganimate api eg if I run `$animate.leave();`in a controller I get an error thrown from angular-animate, indicating the module is loaded successfully. Also adding breakpoints in the ng animate file works

Comment: I believe there were some bugs with ngAnimate in 1.4.0 that should be fixed in 1.4.1 - have you tried 1.3.x to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @RobertMesserle hmm reverting all angular dependencies to `~1.3` actually fixed the issue. Thanks! Do you want to create an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 2):

There were some issues with ngAnimate in Angular 1.4.0 that are being resolved for 1.4.1.  You might want to rollback to 1.3 until 1.4.1 is released.

Comment: Hmm, I've just upgraded to 1.4.1 and still no luck with getting any animations working

Comment: I am on 1.4.3 and animation isn't working with Angular Material either. Sidebar, FAB Toolbar, animations are broken.

Comment: What version of Angular Material are you using?  And have you (or could you) check against HEAD?  (We are close to releasing 0.10.1, which has some changes to animation that may address your issue.)

Comment: HEAD also has a more long-term fix that will not be in 0.10.1, but will be in 0.11.

Comment: Came across this while looking at a similar issue : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12267